# calculus area of enclosed curve

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $(\frac{x}{a}+\frac{y}{b})^5=\frac{x^3}{h^3}-\frac{y^3}{k^3}$ , $y=0$. Find area of enclosed curve. (We should use polar coordinates)

My approach : Substitute  $x=ar\cos^2\phi$ , $y=ar\sin^2\phi$. Then given condition gives us $r^2=\frac{a^3\cos^6\phi}{h^3}-\frac{b^3\sin^6\phi}{k^3}$. If we calculate partial derivatives then Jacobian will be $$J=2abr\sin\phi\cos\phi=abr\sin2\phi$$. So, i conclude that area of enclosed curve is $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{\frac{a^3\cos^6\phi}{h^3}-\frac{b^3\sin^6\phi}{k^3}}}1\cdot|J|drd\phi$$.

But the answer in the book is completely different and complicated. What am i missing? Please help to solve this problem.
Thanks

Comment: One thing you might be missing is the fact that $y=0$ intersects with the given curve three times (assuming $a$ and $h$ have the same sign) at $(0,0)$, $\left(-\sqrt{\frac{a^5}{h^3}},0\right)$, and $\left(\sqrt{\frac{a^5}{h^3}},0\right)$, and creates two symmetric bounded regions. So if your integral is set up correctly, you may just be off by a factor of $2$.

Comment: @user170231 thanks for your response. Jacobian is true o calculated several times. Please write completely that which integrals do i have to calculate? I will do myself just i need correct bounds and integral form. Thank you

Comment: The upper limit for angle integration can't be too large, otherwise the radius will become an imaginary number. And the fact that you have a different formula does not mean that the answers are not equivalent

Comment: @Andrei so? what is  conclusion?

Comment: The upper limit is not $\pi/2$. Calculate the angle where $r=0$. For angles larger than that, $r^2<0$

Comment: @Andrei oh okey. I tried a little bit. So I found $r=\sqrt{a^3/h^3*\cos^6\phi-....}$  as above here $\tan \phi=\sqrt{ak/(bh)}$. hence $\phi=\arctan\sqrt(ak/bh)$

Comment: That sounds right

Comment: @Andrei so integral turns to $$\int_{0}^{\arctan\sqrt{ak/bh)}}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{a^3/h^3*\cos^6\phi...}}2abr\sin\phi\cos\phi drd\phi$$. But again answers are not coincide

Comment: Please edit your question to show what answer you expect

Comment: I have the same answer as you. The answer in the book is if you have powers of 2 instead of 3 on the right hand side

Comment: @Andrei thank you sir i got it . The integral is true i should be careful on calculations. Great!